# Jquery ajax not getting called in asp.net2.0?

Tags: web-services, jquery, asp.net-2.0

I am using Asp.Net 2.0.I am trying to learn webservice and call that webservice using jquery ajax method

The problem is jquery ajax is not working properly and i could not find out where i have gone wrong.

Here's my jquery code

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Button1").click(function(){

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"/WebService.asmx/GetDateTime",
            data:"{}",
            contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType:"json",
            succss: function(msg){                  
                alert("Success");
            },
            failure:function(response){
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    });
 });

 </script>
```

Heres my webservice

```
[WebMethod]
public string GetDateTime()
{
    return DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Heres the HTML part

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>      
    <input type="button" id="Button1" style="width:75px" value="Submit" />
    <span id="output"></span>
</div>     
</form>
```

Comment: can you show us your html?

Comment: @gdp Sorry for the late reply..I have updated the HTML part.Kindly have a look into it.

Comment: Have you check the response with fiddler or the chrome network tab? Whats the actual response/error?

Answer (score 0):

If your button generated dynamically use **"live"** to bind event

```
$("#Button1").live("click", function(){...});
```

Note : make sure your id is same as generated in page, ASP.NET changes id to 'ct00_button1' check in browser inspect element

Comment: Sorry for the late reply..I have updated the HTML part.Kindly have a look into it.